# How to call a javascript function with different names

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a javascript library and I was wondering how jQuery uses two names for the same function. Thats what I mean:

```
jQuery('#div').fadeIn(); and
$('#div').fadeIn(); are the same
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: as in `var $ = jQuery` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jquery` is aliased to `$`, like

```
var $ = jQuery
```

That's all.